# Image not returned by didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm basically trying to 'get' an image from the users photo library (or camera).
The problem is, no image is returned *when on iPad* (Compatibility mode).
Here is the code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSLog(@"info: %@", info);
}
```

iPhone and iPhone simulator log (Original image exists):

```
info: {
UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.image";
UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = "<UIImage: 0x6b6b4e0>";
UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=39D9190B-064F-4C80-9B93-B4CA4FE01B22&ext=JPG";
}
```

iPad and iPad simulator (Compatibility mode) log: (there is no Original Image!)

```
 info: {
UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.image";
UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=72AF462A-A8CE-4474-9535-B59A3154087D&ext=JPG";
}
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? I really need the iPad image.

I tried getting the image from the assets library (am i doing this correctly?), but the image is null.

```
NSURL *imageSource = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
UIImage *image1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[imageSource absoluteString]];
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

**EDIT:** I tried building the application in the iPad 4.3 simulator. Here there are no problems in retrieving the image - the original image exists in the info dictionary. Is there another way to do it in IOS 5?

Comment: well just grab the image from the asset...

Comment: Same for me as well. I tried with all the iPad Simulators from version 5.0,5.1 and 6.0. All returns nil. It works okay in my iPad (Device) with OS 5.1.1 though. I think it is just a bug on the sim.

Comment: I filed a bug to apple but they never replied...

Comment: This is unbelievable. I've been struggling for an hour to solve this, and it turns out to be a bug in the simulator which has been reported and unfixed for at least a year?

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the iPad has the image, it sounds like a bug.

But since you can get the reference url, you can use ALAsset API to get the image.

sorry, it should be `ALAssets`.

For your reference,

```
- (void)assetForURL:(NSURL *)assetURL resultBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)resultBlock failureBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)failureBlock
```

it is a method of  `ALAssetsLibrary`.

For more, you can check the document from Apple.

Comment: I think it's sounds like a bug as well. Can you post the code of getting the image from the AVAsset API?